# Extract Try/Catch blocks - Microsoft convention/standard

Tags: java, coding-style, standards, conventions

I'm reading the book 'Clean Code' of Robert C. Martin and he strongly recommend to *"extract the bodies of the try and catch blocks out into functions of their own"*

Here is the book example, to make it clear:

```
public void delete(Page page)
{
    try
    {
        deletePageAndAllReferences(page);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logError(e);
    }
}

private void deletePageAndAllReferences(Page page) throws Exception {
    deletePage(page);    
    registry.deleteReference(page.name);           
    configKeys.deleteKey(page.name.makeKey());  
}

private void logError(Exception e) {    
    logger.log(e.getMessage());  
}
```

The reasons to do that are:

- try/catch blocks confuse the structure of the code and mix error processing with normal processing
- nice separation that makes the code easier to understand and modify.

The thing is, I've been working for a few years over several project and this never was a rule, and I didn't find people who follow this even in environments where they really care about clean code.

So I want to know:
The book examples are based on Java and I'm working with C#/.NET, there is any standard or convention coming from Microsoft of from the .NET community about this?

Comment: Welcome to the real world; how many people do even the basic things stressed in "Code Complete"? I remember a fresh-out-of-college coder arriving on a project and practically screaming, "The specs! The specs! Where are the functional specs!" As the Rolling Stones sang and played, You Can't Always Get What You Want.

Comment: Someone might come across `deletePageAndAllReferences()` one day and say _"Who's the silly nincompoop who didn't put any try-catch here?  Let me add one"_.  Then you end up with a try-catch in a try-catch doing wonders for performance

Comment: Is this java or C# (`throws Exception {`)?

Comment: @Rob OP says example is from the book which is Java

Comment: Eh, the funny thing is he's saying it's because a method should "do one thing". But clearly the extracted method does two different things, deleting pages and all references. Should have been two separate methods according to his own principles.

Comment: @Micky Right, thought so - retagging now

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Good spot.  I dunno...these glass-house-residing authors :P

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Yes, of course lot of people is not following standards or conventions in the real world, but is that a excuse for not doing so? I can understand the case of the specs, maybe that it's not your responsibility, it's not depending on you but is not the case...

Comment: @Micky Agree with this point. But, what if is the convention around the application? Today, IDE's and another tools (like Resharper in .NET) make things really easy to find all the usages, shouldn't be an excuse

Comment: @Rob Hi Rob, the code sample is in Java, but shouldn't be in any particular section. This apply to almost all the languages that have a try/catch. Actually, I'm programming in C#. This is about good practices

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Agree with you here. I think that probably he can say that those functions are in the 'same level of abstraction' so it's not so bad to group them together.

Answer (score 1):

One reason that I can think of is what if the catch block had more than one line to it.  For example if you were logging the error, sending a notification email, and rolling back a database transaction or something.  If you start adding other things to the catch block you'll find yourself having to repeat code.

Comment: Even with only one line it's worth extracting. If later you decide to change your logging from `logger.log(stuff)` to `someOtherLogger.log(stuff)`, you don't want to replace it in a dozen different spots.

Comment: @DavidGreilach Good example David. I agree with Pierre-Luc Pineault as well, even if it's only one line, we should extract that. You think is worth to do that in the try too? I think that Micky have a good point when he said that, if this is not a convention in the whole project, someone can see the extracted function and put the try-catch block and you can end up with a try-catch inside a try-catch